# Why does this code behave differently on C-stdio function overloads? (vfprintf vs. putchar)

Tags: c++, namespaces, stdio

I'm trying to define various functions with the same name as C stdio to prevent unwanted usage.  I encountered an odd situation where the technique works on some functions, but not others.  I cannot explain why `A::fn` calls the stdio version of `vfprintf` instead of the function definition in the `A` namespace.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

namespace A {

    template <typename... Ts>
    void putchar(int ch) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == -1);
    }
    
    template <typename... Ts>
    void vfprintf(FILE* file, const char* fmt, va_list vlist) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == -1);
    }

    void fn(const char* fmt, ...)
    {
        putchar('A'); // fails to compile (as expected)
        va_list vlist;
        va_start(vlist, fmt);
        vfprintf(stdout, "Hello!\n", vlist); // does not fail (not expected)
        va_end(vlist);
    }
}

int main()
{
    A::fn("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Happy to hear comments indicating that there is a better way to restrict C-style I/O (maybe clang-tidy).

Comment: Might be ADL, not sure whether it has priority over the current NS though.

Comment: Doing this is UB, and what might be tripping you up is that gcc sometimes, in an effort to be 'helpful', substitutes one call with another.

Comment: @PaulSanders, where does it say this is UB?

Comment: My guess would be that `vfprintf` is a macro of some sort

Comment: does `#undef putchar` and `#undef vfprintf` make any difference?

Comment: @M.M, no it does not.

Comment: I guess it would be something to do with `va_list` being an array typedef

Comment: @M.M No, I don't think it's that.  I think that both `putchar` and `vfprintf` are reserved _identifiers_, so gcc can interpret them in any way it chooses.  I had a little play at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xPTE315sx), and you can see that gcc has substituted the call to `vfprintf` with a call to `fwrite`, because it has spotted that the format string contains no substitutions and `fwrite` therefore does the same job and is cheaper.  Of course for the OP's purposes you don't want that, but then UB is UB, so...

Comment: @MarkB I've expanded on that in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing standard library routines is UB (citation to follow).  See examples [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9941bcrcx) and [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9941bcrcx) for the kind of trouble this can cause.

**Edit:** OK, here's the promised [citation](https://eel.is/c++draft/reserved.names.general):

> The C++ standard library reserves the following kinds of names:
> ...
> names with external linkage
> ...
> If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by [library], its behavior is undefined.

But, as discussed in the comments, I'm not sure whether you're doing this in a permitted context or not (although, on reflection, I don't think you are), so I'm going to change tack.

There is, in fact, a very simple way to do what you want.  You can do this with [`#pragma GCC poison`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/cpp/Pragmas.html).  So, taking your example, all you need is:

```
#pragma GCC poison putchar vfprintf
```

and you're done.  clang also supports this pragma.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GpD9goijAsqwtOSN).

Hats, rabbits, we can do it all :) (on good days)

Comment: I am not trying to replace the standard library routines.  I am trying to declare a function that happens to have the same name as a standard library routine in my own namespace.  Defining A::sort & A::vector is allowed, even though std definitions exist.

Comment: I didn't say you were.  My understanding is that these _identifiers_ are reserved - i.e. they have a special meaning to the compiler, potentially, and using them (as opposed to declaring something that _looks_ like them) inside a namespace makes no difference to that fact.  I included a godbolt link in my comment to M.M. above which shows this actually happening.